# Unity GameObject.BroadcastMessage() not work on deactivated GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I notice that `GameObject.BroadcastMessage` does not work when the target is deactivated. How do tweak this to make it work in such situation.

Apparently, This `EventOnMonoCallback.cs` script is attached to the `TOOTHPANEL`, and it will trigger on `OnEnable()` but the `_Food` gameobject itself is inactive.

Seems like, BroadcastMessage not work for deactivated child ?

For some reason, the `TOOTHPANEL` can't be in active state until other script set `TOOTHPANEL` gameobject to `true`.

[image]

[image]

## EventOnMonoCallback.cs

```
public class EventOnMonoCallback : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum MonoCallbackType
    {
        Awake,
        Start,
        Update,
        OnEnable,
        OnDisable,
        OnDestroy
    }

    public MonoCallbackType Type;
    public UnityEvent Do;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.Awake)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.Start)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.Update)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.OnEnable)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.OnDisable)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (Type == MonoCallbackType.OnDestroy)
        {
            Do.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using some sort of framework, but if you don't tell us what it is, we can't help you. Either way, it wouldn't be a Unity question, it would be a question about that framework

Comment: @Mars This is a Unity question and is clearly tagged as so.

Comment: It's two questions--the first is asking how to get around broadcastmessage not applying to inactive children, and a second question that OP answers in the first line of the post...

Comment: But after googling, I can't find any reference to EventOnMonoCallback, so I suppose it's a custom script... in which case the answer to the first question changes

Comment: @Tengku What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mars OP simply want to know how to make [`GameObject.BroadcastMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.BroadcastMessage.html) work even when object is disabled. That's what OP mentioned in the question. Nothing more. *"How do tweak this to make it work in such situation."* ...

Comment: That's why I'm asking more about the situation. Does he have control over the scripts in use, or is he using something such as Playmaker? What is being broadcast? Does OP want to enable all children? Only specific children? Many many questions... but if I were to take a guess (which I did), I'd assume the answer I posted is what the OP was trying to accomplish

Comment: It doesn't matter if he has control or not and no Playmaker is mentioned so assume that's not used here. `GameObject.BroadcastMessage`  is used to call a function in an object without provided the function name during compile time. Your solution requires that the function to bind  during compile time. `GameObject.BroadcastMessage` just requires the function name to be passed as a string and I think that's what op is looking for but to also work when object is disabled.

Comment: Of course it matters if they have control or not--if they're working with something like Playmaker where they don't have control, then you need a Playmaker solution, not a coding solution. Anyway, the OP is setting the function in editor, so it seems more likely that OP is fine with it not being done at runtime. But if you feel the OP has provided enough info, I'm sure they'd be pleased with an alternative answer as well :)

Comment: @Mars I already update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: what @Programmer said is right, i did not use any plugin, it just how unity script works, but in my condition i need to tweak it. Of course easy way to enable `TOOTHPANEL` . but then it will create lots of issue.

Comment: So, does my solution work when GameObject is deactivated? That method should replace BroadcastMessage.

Comment: @Programmer I have temporary solution yesterday, and since today need to publish it because few people need to test the app I am little bit worried to change it. But later i ll try it because doing it the right way are very important. Once I try it I will let you know, I got a good feeling it will work since I understand the logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between activating/deactivating and enabling/disabling in Unity. You can activate  and deactivate GameObjects. You can enable and disable scripts. Do not confuse these two.

The `BroadcastMessage` function **will always work** even when the script with the target function is *disabled* but it will **not** work when the GameObject that script is attached to is *deactivated*.

---

There are two easy workarounds:

**1**.Use Unity's builtin [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) function. Use `GetComponentsInChildren` to get all `MonoBehaviour` then call `Invoke` on each one. Invoke will always work even when the GameObject is *deactivated*. Use the overload version of `GetComponentsInChildren` that take `List` as parameter so that it does not create garbage each time it is called.

```
List<MonoBehaviour> monoList = new List<MonoBehaviour>();


void BroadcastMessageExt(string methodName)
{
    targetObj.GetComponentsInChildren<MonoBehaviour>(true, monoList);
    for (int i = 0; i < monoList.Count; i++)
    {
        monoList[i].Invoke(methodName, 0);
    }
}
```

The only bad thing about this is that you cannot pass a parameter to it. See **#2** for workaround.

---

**2**.Do the-same thing as **#1** but use C# [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) function instead of the version from Unity API. This should let you pass a parameter to the function you are calling.

```
List<MonoBehaviour> monoList = new List<MonoBehaviour>();


void BroadcastMessageExt(string methodName, object value = null, SendMessageOptions options = SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver)
{
    targetObj.GetComponentsInChildren<MonoBehaviour>(true, monoList);
    for (int i = 0; i < monoList.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Type type = monoList[i].GetType();

            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance |
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                             BindingFlags.Public |
                                             BindingFlags.Static);

            method.Invoke(monoList[i], new object[] { value });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Re-create the Error thrown by the original SendMessage function
            if (options == SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver)
                Debug.LogError("SendMessage " + methodName + " has no receiver!");

            //Debug.LogError(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can turn these into [*extension methods*](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) to make them more easier to use.

Comment: I don't quite get it for `monoList`, do i need to cache all the MonoBehaviours in awake ? and regarding parameter, I can put it in `value` ? what if i have two parameter ?

Comment: `monoList` will be automatically cleared and re-filled when `GetComponentsInChildren<MonoBehaviour>(true, monoList);` is called in that function. You don't have to cache anything in the `Awake` function but that question is why trying an answer before making a comment is really recommended. It shows you care about your question and the answers you have received.

Comment: As for two parameters, this question is about `BroadcastMessage` which takes one parameter. I  made the answer to take one parameter too and wanted it to act exactly like the original `BroadcastMessage` function *but also work when the GameObject is deactivated.*  You need to modify it yourself if you want something else. Looking into the `method.Invoke` section.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, BroadcastMessage does not work for inactive objects. You will have to enable it some way other than by BroadcastMessage or SendMessage.
If you have a reference to the object, you could enable with that.

If your goal is to just call a function in all applicable children, you could try something like:

```
void Call_YOURFUNCTION_OnChildren(){
    Transform[] transforms = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
    foreach (Transform t in transforms){
        if (t.GetComponent<YOURCLASS>()){
            t.GetComponent<YOURCLASS>().YOURFUNCTION();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this assumes that all of your objects have transforms

Comment: I have been thinking this method too, but what if I have others different function name ? I want to avoid creating a lots of script by creating something generic. So if I use `BroadcastMessage`, I can put anything in the string parameter to execute the method.

Comment: In that case, you can use Delegates or Interfaces to try to get varied effects, but the call would still be essentially the same I think.